# How to restrict a member to just have view rights?

Tags: trello, access-control

We have business clients who would like visibility of the work that we do. Which is fine, but we would like them only to view. The commenting, moving or changing options on all the cards should not be available to specific business users.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Read-only observer members are now available in Trello Business Class: see 'Observer Role' at https://trello.com/business-class